# Calling step in step definitons

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd

I'm trying to call a step that takes an argument in an another step definitions but i'm getting an error like

> Cucumber::UndefinedDynamicStep: Undefined dynamic step: "And user
>   select Electronics as category group from dropdown list"

```
.feature file
And   user fill the create new category form "Electronics"

.rb file
And(/^user fill the create new category form "([^"]*)"$/) do |name|
    step "And user type name #{name}"

And(/^user type name "([^"]*)"$/) do |name|
  find(:id, 'namePanelGroup').set(name)
end
```

How can i handle with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add escaped double quotes because the step you are calling has double quotes around the regex, and you need to remove the "And" like so:

```
step "user type name \"#{name}\""
```

Comment: I changed the step as you typed but i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you show the exact error now that you have updated your code?

Comment: So sorry. It was my fault. It's okay now. Thank you!!:)

Comment: No worries and Brilliant! Glad I could help :)